# jquery and ajax where this technologies are used?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing project where i'm going to use Jquery and ajax. I'm starting to learn this technology,i hv one doubt abt where does this jquery and ajax are used, are they used for same purpose. can anybody tell me situtation where jquery or ajax can be used both are for same purpose or different ?

and any best book to start with jquery and ajax i'm doing with php ?

Comment: Have you already read the articles about jQuery and Ajax at Wikipedia for a start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is a javascript API. Makes it easier to use javascript (i think so).
Ajax is a fancy name for any communication between a web page and its server.
Bottomline: You can use jQuery to do Ajax easily.

a good place to start jquery would be the jQuery book by Apress publications. That said, I've always relied on online tutorials (google) for my day-to-day needs rather than on a book.

Cheers
jrh

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is basically javascript made easy. AJAX is just a technology to communicate with the server without refreshing the page using javascript.

websites using jQuery:

Google, Dell, microsoft, ...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a javascript library suited for many purposes, on of which is AJAX- a marketing term used to describe asynchronous interaction with the web server.  Really they are two separate things, but simply, jQuery can be used for Ajax (but so can many other tools).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a library of functions written in javascript. It is used on thousands of sites.

AJAX is a method of using Javascript to make calls to your web server without having to reload the whole page. The JQuery library includes functions to allow you to make AJAX calls.

There's lot of books that will teach you JQuery. It sounds like you need one that starts with the basics, so I'm probably not the best person to recommend one. But Amazon will give you plenty of results if you search for JQuery books.